# How can I add each element of one array to another one's corresponding element using a ParallelStream?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

What I am trying to do is probably easier explained using an example. Let's assume I have to following two arrays:

```
int firstArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int secArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

What I want is to add each element `i` of the second array to each element `i` of the first array. Of course, creating a third array is also okay.

The result, given this example, would be: `2, 4, 6, 8, 10`

Can I do this somehow using a ParallelStream in Java 8? I can only think of solutions using at least one index, and they don't really work because of the parallelism (which also defeats the purpose).

This single threaded approach works:

```
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
int resultArray[] = Arrays.stream(firstArray)
                          .map(a -> a + secArray[i.getAndIncrement()]).toArray();
```

But if I try this using a parallel stream, the results are (of course they are) random and the program is really slow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a typical use case for `IntStream`:

```
IntStream.range(0, firstArray.length).parallel()
    .forEach(i -> { secArray[i] += firstArray[i]; });
```

If you need the result in a separate array, you can use the same approach:

```
int[] result = IntStream.range(0, firstArray.length).parallel()
    .map(i -> firstArray[i] + secArray[i])
    .toArray();
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether your second approach preserves order in your current approach. I don't think so, unless `toArray()` guarantees that. You could solve it by first creating the array and then using a similar approach as in your first example.

Comment: @skiwi: I agree, that the documentation of `IntStream::toArray` isn't clear about this issue. However, based on the way fork-join algorithms work, it would be really surprising if the order is not preserved.

Comment: An alternative is `Arrays.parallelSetAll(result, i -> first[i] + second[i])`. Doesn't use streams though, which might end up being faster.